# Disable div works in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, browser

Button inside the disabled div is working in chrome. In Firefox its not working.

```
$(".div_class").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

someone will have experience in it. please give your suggestions.

thanks

Hi all,
Here the solution for this quetion

```
$(".div_class).find('input,textarea,select,button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: You said you have a button, why don't you just disable the button instead of the `div`?

Comment: @karthikr, for me div is disabled but the button is till working. this problem is only in chrome. in firefox its fine

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.prop( propertyName, value )`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) instead of [`.attr( attributeName, value )`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)

Also disable `button` not `.div_class`:

```
$(".div_class button").prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: aaah its div, ... I EDIT

Comment: please explain why, IE after jQuery 1.6 attr is no longer the same and prop was added....blah blah blah

Comment: all informations about difference between _attributes_ and _properties_ you can find here - http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: I meant to add it to your answer no the comments...This is the correct answer but seriously without context the next person to come to here is just going to get the solution without the why it fixes it...hardly teaching them anything.

Comment: OK I improved answer :)

Answer (score 0):

[As per Docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html) It didn't make any sense that disabling a `div` as there is no attribute or property called disabled for a div `element`.forget about `div` disable the `button`

```
$('#buttonselector').prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: thanks, i had repeated the div with unique id. every div will have separate disable button. also i'm not having only button in it. i have some other data also in it.